# How can i get the Width and Height of self-adaptived form in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

My Main Form is also self-adaptived and its "windowState" is "Maximized".

I set the width of it 1022px in design Properties.

When running the application in fullscreen, the form.width is still 1022 , but not the screen resolution.

how can i get right value?

Comment: Do you want the size of the display or the size of the window area?

Comment: Do you mean your screen resolution may change variably? I think a screen shot of your window is better for us to see your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the `Window` is maximized you can use [`Screen.WorkingArea`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.workingarea%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the true dimensions.

Comment: Thank you @Oren. Actually, the way is Screen.AllScreens[0].WorkingArea , it's returnd a Rectangle contains width & height. All i have just one screen so the index of AllScreens is 0!. BTW, how i can get the width or height of the self-adaptived component, just like panel's or picturebox's. do i must to calculate when app is running?

Comment: yup, my point was more about the property itself :) For the containers you might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14206634/when-is-panel-size-updated-after-adding-controls-when-panel-autosize-true